# osm2pgsql --hstore

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm working with PostgreSQL 8.$ and PostGIS and I need to import an OSM file to the database. I tried it with the utility osm2pgsql, but I have problem with the hstore extension.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image: error while opening file --hstore]

Comment: Is the `hstore` extension installed? (For 8.4: `$ psql -d gis -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/hstore.sql`).

Comment: Yes,I tried to uninstall and again istall...but i have still same error with osm2pgsql....

Comment: What's happening if you put `--hstore` before the files calls ? `osm2pgsql -U postgres -d postgis20 --hstore -S ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to write `--hstore` (or `-k`) before I write path to the osm file:

```
osm2pgsql "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\osm2pgsql\x64\map.osm" -d postgis20 -U postgres -P 5432 -S --hstore "C:\Users\Ludva\Desktop\osm2pgsql\default.style"
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

2) It appears it is trying to read `--hstore` as the file so try placing the `osm` file path after `osm2pgsql` like [this tutorial](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=loading_osm_postgis):
`osm2pgsql "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\osm2pgsql\x64\map.osm" -d postgis20 -U postgres -P 5432 -S "C:\Users\Ludva\Desktop\osm2pgsql\default.style" --hstore`

1) Try `-k` in place of `--hstore`as shown in the [osm2pgsql docs](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#hstore) for `--hstore`.

Comment: This makes same error...(error while opening file -k)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for osm2pgsql is `osm2pgsql [options] planet.osm.{pbf,gz,bz2}`. Like most command-line programs, osm2pgsql takes the input file name at the **end** of the command line.